# Using Threads to watch input in C with Time Counting

Tags: c, multithreading

I am trying to use threads in C in Windows. I want to use a thread to watch whether a user inputs within 3 seconds. But after using TerminateThread() to end this thread, the scanf() stucks the procedure, unable to perform any operation except quitting. The detail is that when time is out, I input, and the procedure seems like want me to input again, but I can't input..

Being new to threads, I don't know a better way to use them or to implement the function, would appreciate all the advice.
Here is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <stdio.h>
       
unsigned Count;
int recored = 0;
unsigned __stdcall

Func (void *pArguments)
{
  scanf ("%d", &Count);
  recored = 1;
  printf ("thread\n");
  _endthreadex (0);
  return 0;
}

int main ()
{
  HANDLE hThread;
  DWORD threadExitCode;
  int a;
  unsigned threadID;
  printf ("Thread start:\n");
  hThread = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex (NULL, 0, &Func, NULL, 0, &threadID);
  WaitForSingleObject (hThread, 3000);
  TerminateThread (hThread, 0);
  CloseHandle (hThread);
  printf ("Time over\n");
  if (recored == 1)
    {
      printf ("input:%d\n", Count);
    }
  else
    printf ("OUTDATE\n");
  printf ("Last Test\n");
  scanf ("%d", &a);
  printf ("input:%d  %d\n", Count, a);
}
```

Comment: Don't ever call `TerminateThread` just an FYI. That's basically killing the thread immediately without doing any cleanup and de-facto puts the process in an undefined state. Let threads exit normally in almost all cases.

Comment: Thanks for your help.But  I don't know how to kill a thread in another thread without using TerminateThread() , could you please give me more hints about this?

Comment: You don't, if you need a thread to end you need to use tools like cancellation tokens to ask the thread to quietly exit appropriately. But those aren't really implemented in C AFAIK although there is nothing preventing that. Generally if you need a thread to be cancellable you wouldn't do blocking IO like `scanf` ever on that thread. But outright killing a thread in a hostile manner like `TerminateThread`, you should ***NEVER*** do that as it basically means that the program behavior is undefined after that point. That method exists for some rare corner cases.